# KMenu & shell script

Tags: bash, kubuntu

I'm trying to make a very small shell script with a simple command and add it up to the KMenu.

Well, thing is that once it launches the shell script, it closes it fast and I want to leave it open because the shell script attempts to create run a web application using a framework.

I tried with this first

```
#!/bin/bash

play run /home/david/Projects/ZS
```

then I tried with this

```
#!/bin/bash

konsole -e play run /home/david/Projects/ZS
```

In terminal, it runs perfectly, but in launcher.. not so much

Any solution or suggestion is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
play run /home/david/Projects/ZS
echo "Press Enter to exit"
read
```

and using this command in the menu:

```
konsole -e "bash path/to/shell/script"
```

Comment: works like a charm, though I detected a weird behavior in Konsole, I try to re-use it to open more tabs and it opens the same shell script... nothing to worry about though I'll ask in KDE forums